# Can i stop esbuild from emitting css file of my server part of my ssr app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, esbuild

I have a SSR pet project, and recently i swaped from webpack to esbuild. But after bundling my app, i got another .css file from server part. Can i stop esbuild from doing that?

package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "client": "esbuild src/index.tsx --bundle --outfile=built/app.js",
    "server": "node ./esbuild.config.js",
    "start": "node built/server.js",
    "build": "npm run client && npm run server",
    "all": "npm run client && npm run server && npm run start"
  },
```

esbuild.config.js

```
const esbuild = require('esbuild');
const { nodeExternalsPlugin } = require('esbuild-node-externals');

esbuild.build({
  entryPoints: ['src/server.jsx'],
  bundle: true,
  platform: 'node',
  outfile: 'built/server.js',
  plugins: [nodeExternalsPlugin()],
}).catch(() => process.exit(1))
```

result of bundling

[image: result of bundling]